# Python Regex: Match and replace string instances in openpyxl range

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Let's say we have a given cell in range in excel described as "**A1:C1000**"

If I have to replace '**1**' with '**10**' and '**1000**' to '**999**'
Using the re.sub() how would I generate the expression to replace the string to be "**A10:C999**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

#### Regex 1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YUnlbB/1)

```
([A-Z]+)1\b
```

Replacement: `\g<1>10`
Results in `A10:C1000`

#### Regex 2

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YUnlbB/2)

```
([A-Z]+)1000\b
```

Replacement `\g<1>999`
Results in `A10:C999`

#### Single Regex

```
([A-Z]+)(\d+)\b
```

Using `re.sub` callback...

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/hPIkTg)

```
import re

s = "A1:C1000"
r = r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)\b"

def mySub(m):
    letter = m.group(1)
    contents = m.group(2)
    if contents == '1':
        return letter + '10'
    if contents == '1000':
        return letter + '999'

print re.sub(r, mySub, s)
```

---

### Explanation

- `([A-Z]+)` Capture one or more uppercase ASCII characters into capture group 1
- `1` (or 1000, or whatever you want) Match this literally. In the callback method `(\d+)` captures one or more digits into capture group 2
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary